# Python multiprocessing refuses to split up my iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to write a multiprocessed program and it seems I have done it and I have verified with the System Monitor app that the Python processes are created. But the thing is that it appears almost all of them are not utilized in reality. In my program I am trying to split audio files in chunks, so I don't consider it to be a "trivial computational load" as I have read in other threads.

A minimal example that shows the same behavior for me:

```py
import os, random, time
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool

def myfunc(myli):
    print(len(myli))
    for item in myli:
        x = item*item*item
        time.sleep(2)
    return

mylist = [random.randint(1,10000) for _ in range (0, 19999)]

with Pool(processes=8) as p, tqdm(total=len(mylist)) as pbar:
    for _ in p.imap_unordered(func=myfunc, iterable=(mylist,)):
        pbar.update()
```

As you see I have added a `print()` inside the `func` used, and every time it prints the length of the entire array. As if no splitting is happening.

I have naively tried using different chunksizes and removing tqdm (as if it plays any role).

If you could give me any insight, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the multiprocessing Manager class. You can't share mylist across sub-processes like that. It would work with multithreading because in that case the address space is shared and also because lists are thread-safe

Comment: @JCaesar Hi ty for the answer. I remember looking into the Manager class and not using it as it seemed overkill. Why do you think it's necessary? As I understand it just splitting an iterable into processes that don't talk to each other or share data is all you need. Or should be...

Comment: Perhaps if you could provide more detail around exactly what you need to achieve, I'm sure you'll get a more complete answer. Also worth noting that your sub-processes are very likely to appear under-utilised because they're spending the vast majority of their time sleeping

Comment: My understanding is that `mylist` is not shared between the processes as it is split in smaller chunks which are independent for every process. Regarding the details, it's nothing fancy. I want to process a bunch of items (strings) that I have in a list. And the processing of one item doesn't affect the processing of the others. The sleeping part is only for the example here, as I said in the post I work with audio files in the main app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is doing what you told it to do: you passed an iterable of length 1, a tuple containing a single item (`mylist`). So it passes that single item to a single worker to process.

But you can't do `iterable=mylist` instead, because `myfunc()` expects to get a sequence, not an integer. Whatever the iterable is, `multiprocessing` passes it to the worker one element at a time. `chunksize` has nothing to do with that. Whether `chunksize` is 1 or a billion, the worker functions see one element at a time. `chunksize` is an under-the-covers optimization, purely to reduce the number of expensive interprocess communication calls required.

If you want to split a sequence into chunks and use worker functions that expect chunks, then you have to do the "chunking" yourself. For example, add

```
# Generate slices of `xs` of length (at most) `n`.
def chunkit(xs, n):
    start = 0
    while start < len(xs):
        yield xs[start : start + n]
        start += n
```

and pass `iterable=chunkit(mylist, 40)`. Then all 8 processes will be busy. One will work on `mylist[0:40]`, another on `mylist[40:80]`, another on `mylist[80:120]`, and so on, until `mylist` is exhausted.

Comment: Ok, this explanation is exactly what I needed. So my mistake, when trying to simply pass `mylist`, was the `for` loop in `myfunc`. I didn't think that processes take elements one by one, while it seems obvious now... Thank you, Tim!

Comment: Right! Change `myfunc()` to take an integer, and the original code should work then (using `iterable=mylist` too). Things _will_ be chunked under the covers, and you can use `chunksize=` to control that, but it's just an optimization: it doesn't change that your worker function will see one integer at a time. It instead controls how many arguments are sent, under the covers, in each interprocess communication call.  This chunking is invisible to your code.